# grep with or and fixed

Tags: r, regex

Actually i have tried to grep different files name but its not working with grep just because of brackets while its worked for **match**

```
 match("248465_abc_S(R).doc",Role[,"Name.of.file"])
   [1] 9
   grep("248465_abc_S(R).doc",Role[,"Name.of.file"])
   integer(0)
```

as i have different format as in doc,docx so i cant use match, i used **fixed=T** ,its working with single name but not with **OR**

```
grep("248465_abc_S(R)",Role[,"Name.of.file"],fixed = TRUE)
[1] 9
grep(paste(names,collapse="|"),Role[,"Name.of.files"]) #some names still missing because of brackets
[1]  6 11 14 17 26 27 28
grep(paste(names,collapse="|"),Role[,"Name.of.files"],fixed = TRUE)
integer(0)
```

**EDIT**

```
paste(name,collapse="|")
[1] "115457_dfm(R)|248465_sdj_S(R)[1]|248471_sdjb(R)[1]|28837_FS
grep(paste(gsub("]","\\]",gsub("[","\\[",gsub(".","\\.",gsub(")","\\)",gsub("(","\\(",name,fixed=T),fixed=T),fixed=T),fixed=T),fixed=T),collapse="|"),Role[,"Name.of.files"])
[1]  6  9 10 11 12 14 17 18 20 21 22 26 27 28
```

instead of indentify **each and every character** to escaped ,Is their any better approach,thanks.

Comment: Maybe using `gsub("(", "\\(", paste(name,collapse="|"), fixed = T)` as the pattern to `grep` helps?

Comment: Could you, just, loop through the elements of `name` and `grep` them with `fixed = T`? I.e. something like `sapply(name, function(x) grep(x, .., fixed = T)`?

Answer (score 1):

`match` takes in actual value to be searched.
`grep` takes in a `regex` pattern to be searched. `(` and `)` have special meaning in regex.
To use brackets within the pattern, you need to escape them with `\\`. Same is applicable to `.` as well.

Try below, and see if that's what you want.

```
grep("248465_abc_S\\(R\\)\\.doc",Role[,"Name.of.file"])
```

Comment: `.` also has special meaning!

Comment: @ChinmayPatil as u can see ,I am directly using all the "name",i cant do this manually for each and every name.

Comment: @Aashu - perhaps you can update question with more information about the data and then we can help.

Comment: He can also simply add the `fixed = TRUE` argument. (i.e. `grep("248465_abc_S(R).doc",Role[,"Name.of.file"],fixed=TRUE)`)